# I Can't Get The Virtual Include To Work, Do I need an extension?

Tags: php, html

so I have the include saved in a folder called "include" and the file name is menu. When I upload the site, it doesn't show. Do I need an extension? Do I have to do it with php? Help me please. Here's my code. the website is [www.martinshaba.zzl.org](http://martinshaba.zzl.org)

```
    </head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header_line">
  <div class="header">

<!--#include virtual="/inlcude/menu.html" -->


    <p><a href="/index.php">MARTIN SHABA</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The #include tag is nothing to do with PHP, but is an [Apache module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#element.include). That module itself is, however, rarely used these days, and so you may do better to indeed use PHP, though you will have to name the file with a .php extension for that to be parsed.

```
<div class="header">
<?php
include "/include/menu.html";
?>
<p><a href="/index.php">MARTIN SHABA</a></p> <!-- etc.... -->
```